# How to receive events for any notifications appearing on notitication bar in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I could not find a way to receive events for any notifications like email, SMS, battery charged, etc.. which is appearing on the notification bar.

Note: I could receive events for sms, email, etc.. but I am looking for a event trigger when notification bar is get updated by any app

your suggestions and advices are highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) and set it to listen to TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED events. This way, each time any of the application packages specified while configuring the AccessibilityService generates a new notification, the onAccessibilityEvent callback of your service will be called with all the information about the notification.

Answer (score 1):

you can't read info from the notifications bar.
you'll need to try and listen for broadcast for events for every type you want (in casse they exist - not all of the apps send broadcast when they send a messege to the notifications bar)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. The start point is [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html), but it doesn't offer an API to listen for all notifications.